# How to sort a list of months with years

Tags: java, arrays, date, datetime, time

I have a list of months with years such as: `[12-2014,11-2012,5-2014,8-2012]` and I have to sort them *with the most recent on top (or the latest date on top)* eg. `[12-2014,5-2014,11-2012,8-2012]` . 
Does anybody have any idea on how to do this in `Java` efficiently?

**EDIT:** 
The class `YearMonth` is not available, I'm on `Java 7`

Comment: Well, it sounds like you should have a `YearMonth` class to retain the year and month, and make it implement `Comparable<YearMonth>`...

Comment: writing code would be a good start. if those are strings, then just split the string on the `-`, convert the parts to integers, then sort on those integers.

Comment: If you use `YearMonth` you can use something like `date1.isBefore(date2)` and `date1.isAfter(date2)`

Comment: @JonSkeet Even better, YearMonth already implements Comparable<YearMonth>: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html
So just use Collections.sort or Stream.sorted and maybe Collections.reverseOrder.

Comment: While `YearMonth` was indeed introduced with java.time, the modern Java date and time API, in Java 8, java.time has also been backported to Java 6 and 7. Use the [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Java 7 you can take advantage of the Date class as well as the Comparator interface and its usage in a Set object like the treeSet for instance.

Here is an implementation of the Comparator interface to compare two dates

```
public class MonthYearComparator implements Comparator<Date> {

    public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return -1*o1.compareTo(o2);
    }

}
```

And then here is how we could use it. First I will use a SimpleDateFormat class to parse your strings as dates. To do that I need to complete them and make them look as formated date strings. Since the day is irrelevant for the comparison I could take any day like "01".

Once I have turned them into Date objects I will add them to a instance of a TreeSet which is provided with a Comparator and they will automatically be sorted as I add them.

Then I can substract the part of the date that I need which will be a substring(3) of my date object after being formated as a string.

Here is the code (for demo sake I used the same datas that you provided as example):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MonthYearIssue {

    private List<String> listOfMonthYears = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static final String USED_DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(USED_DATE_FORMAT);

    public void setUpMonthYearsList() {
        listOfMonthYears.add("12-2014");
        listOfMonthYears.add("11-2012");
        listOfMonthYears.add("5-2014");
        listOfMonthYears.add("8-2012");
    }

    public Date parseToDate(String monthYearString) throws ParseException {
        return formatter.parse("01-" + monthYearString);
    }

    public List<String> doSort() throws ParseException {

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        Set<Date> dates = new TreeSet<Date>(new MonthYearComparator());

        for (String monthYearStr: listOfMonthYears) {
            dates.add(parseToDate(monthYearStr));

        }

        for (Object d: dates.toArray()) {

            result.add(formatter.format((Date)d).substring(3));
        }

        System.out.println(result);
        return result;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        MonthYearIssue issueSolver = new MonthYearIssue();
        issueSolver.setUpMonthYearsList();
        issueSolver.doSort();
    }

}
```

Here is the result:

**[12-2014, 05-2014, 11-2012, 08-2012]**

Comment: While the solution works for the given input, there are several issues with the code: 1. Using a Set will cause to loose duplicate entries. Use Collections.sort, if you want to sort a List. 2. You don't have to write an inverse Comparator, the JDK already provides a generic one: Collections.reverseOrder(). 3. Why add "01-", format "dd-" and then calling subset? I think simply using MM-yyyy should work (I haven't tested what the default day will be, but I think it shouldn't matter and it shouldn't throw an error).

Comment: @Puce thanks for your comments.I thought of using MM-yyyy but without knowing the day, I picked up one since it is irrelevant.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 6):

## Java-8 onwards

Create a `Stream` out of the list, map each `String` of the `Stream` into `YearMonth` using a `DateTimeFormatter`, sort the `Stream` using [`Comparator#reverseOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--), map each `YearMonth` element of the Stream into the `String` using the same `DateTimeFormatter` and finally, collect the `Stream` into a `List<String>`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> list = List.of("12-2014", "11-2012", "5-2014", "8-2012");
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        List<String> sorted = 
                list.stream()
                    .map(s -> YearMonth.parse(s, dtf))
                    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                    .map(ym -> dtf.format(ym))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Display the list
        System.out.println(sorted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[12-2014, 5-2014, 11-2012, 8-2012]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/kq5Xth)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

use a custom String comparator. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

I can write the code out if you would like.

Here is some sudo code for now:

```
Arrays.sort(yearList, new Comparator<String>{

    //get the year and month of o1 and o2 as ints

    //if the years are different then return the difference of the years

    //if the years are the same then return the difference of the months

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like (now tested):

```
private final static DateTimeFormatter YEAR_MONTH_FORMATTER = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M-yyyy");

...

List<String> yearMonthStrings = ...;
List<YearMonth> yearMonthList = yearMonthStrings.stream()
    .map(s -> YearMonth.parse(s, YEAR_MONTH_FORMATTER))
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// or
List<YearMonth> yearMonthList = yearMonthStrings.stream()
    .map(s -> YearMonth.parse(s, YEAR_MONTH_FORMATTER))
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The latter gives `[2014-12, 2014-05, 2012-11, 2012-08]`.

Comment: The class YearMonth is not available, I'm on Java 7

Comment: Ah, this was edit in the question then. Please note that Oracle's Java SE 7 is planned to go EOL this spring, so in case you're using the Oracle JDK and don't have support contracts with Orcale, it's strongly recommended to upgrade to Java SE 8.

Comment: If anyone is still on Java 7 (AKA 1.7) (can’t be many in 2021), java.time with `YearMonth` and `DateTimeFormatter` has been backported. Use the [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the comparator or comparable and checking the months by splitting them.

Answer (score 1):

The class Date is comparable, so you can create an instance of Date for each String in your array and then you can sort them

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Never use the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`.

Always use their replacement, the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Most of that functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in *ThreeTen-Backport*.

```java
List < String > inputs = Arrays.asList( "12-2014" , "11-2012" , "5-2014" , "8-2012" );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M-uuuu" );

List < YearMonth > yearMonths = new ArrayList <>( inputs.size() );
for ( String input : inputs )
{
    try { yearMonths.add( YearMonth.parse( input , f ) ); } catch ( DateTimeException e ) { System.out.println( "ERROR - Faulty input: " + input ); }
}

Collections.sort( yearMonths , Collections.reverseOrder() );
```

## Back-port *java.time* to Java 7

You said you are restricted to Java 7. While not built-in, most of the modern *java.time* functionality is available to you. Add the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library to your project.

If using Maven, add this to your POM:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
  <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The legacy date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` are terribly flawed in design. They really are such an awful mess that adding a library to your project is well-worth the chore.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

Set up your inputs.

By the way, your input text is using a custom format of M-YYYY. I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for formatting date-time values exchanged textually. The standard format for a year-month is YYYY-MM.

Define a formatter to match your non-standard inputs.

```
List < String > inputs = Arrays.asList( "12-2014" , "11-2012" , "5-2014" , "8-2012" );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M-uuuu" );
```

### `YearMonth`

Parse your inputs a [`YearMonth`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/YearMonth.html#format(org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter)) objects, adding each a new `List`.

If an input might be faulty, you can trap for [`DateTimeException`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeParseException.html) to detect and handle such a problem.

```java
List < YearMonth > yearMonths = new ArrayList <>( inputs.size() );
for ( String input : inputs )
{
    try { yearMonths.add( YearMonth.parse( input , f ) ); } catch ( DateTimeException e ) { System.out.println( "ERROR - Faulty input: " + input ); }
}
```

### `Collections.sort` && `Collections.reverseOrder`

Sort your list. You want the latest first, so pass the optional second argument, a `Comparator` to reverse the sorting on natural-order.

```
Collections.sort( yearMonths , Collections.reverseOrder() );
```

Report our new list.

```
System.out.println( "yearMonths = " + yearMonths );
```

### Example code

Pull all that code together.

```java
package work.basil;

import org.threeten.bp.DateTimeException;
import org.threeten.bp.YearMonth;
import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Example parsing year-month values using ThreeTen-Backport library
 * giving us most of the Java 8+ *java.time* functionality.
 **/
public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        List < String > inputs = Arrays.asList( "12-2014" , "11-2012" , "5-2014" , "8-2012" );
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M-uuuu" );

        List < YearMonth > yearMonths = new ArrayList <>( inputs.size() );
        for ( String input : inputs )
        {
            try { yearMonths.add( YearMonth.parse( input , f ) ); } catch ( DateTimeException e ) { System.out.println( "ERROR - Faulty input: " + input ); }
        }

        Collections.sort( yearMonths , Collections.reverseOrder() );

        System.out.println( "yearMonths = " + yearMonths );
    }
}
```

When run.

> yearMonths = [2014-12, 2014-05, 2012-11, 2012-08]

---

By the way, here is a Maven POM for this app, using the latest versions of various parts.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil</groupId>
    <artifactId>J7</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>J7</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.9.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```